# RSTUDIO finding p values and R-squared for each subsample

Tags: r, p-value

Hi I am very new to **R** and to this forum.

I want to run multiple regressions on subsamples from a large dataset.
Here is a sample of my dataset named "totaldoc":
[image: sample dataset image]

I want to do `lm(numericdiffNGO∼numericdiffmeeting))` for each *issue_name1*.

I tried this command :

```
 lapply(split(totaldoc, f = list(totaldoc$issue_name1)), function(x) lm(numericdiffNGO∼numericdiffmeeting))
```

and this command

```
ddply(totaldoc, "issue_name1", function(df)coefficients (lm(numericdiffNGO∼numericdiffmeeting, data=df)))
```

But it only give me the coefficients  and even not for all the *issu-name1*
What I want to do is to have each p value per subsamples *issu-name1*  and to rank them from the most significant to the highest. And the same for rsquared but for the reverse so, the highest to the lowest.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Comment: yes I will pay attention to it next time

Answer (score 0):

Here's a stab using `mtcars`:

```r
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
  group_nest(cyl) %>%
  mutate(
    model = lapply(data, function(z) lm(mpg ~ disp, data = z)), 
    summ = lapply(model, summary), 
    p.value = sapply(summ, function(z) coef(z)[2,"Pr(>|t|)"]), 
    rsq = sapply(summ, `[[`, "r.squared")
  ) %>%
  arrange(-p.value)
# # A tibble: 3 x 6
#     cyl                data model  summ       p.value    rsq
#   <dbl> <list<tibble[,10]>> <list> <list>       <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1     6            [7 x 10] <lm>   <smmry.lm> 0.826   0.0106
# 2     8           [14 x 10] <lm>   <smmry.lm> 0.0568  0.270 
# 3     4           [11 x 10] <lm>   <smmry.lm> 0.00278 0.648
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I try this tomorrow and keep you in touch!

Comment: I don't get why I have this message of error Error :    in `group_by()`:
! Must group by variables found in `.data`.
x Column `issue_name1` is not found.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: I don't know either, and there's nothing I can do without sample data. It works with this data, it's up to you to show me how it doesn't work with your data.